# Continue python script even if urllib.request encounters HTTP error codes

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-codes, continue

I have a python script that accepts a CSV file containing a list of URLs.  The CSV file looks like this.

```
name, url
google, https://httpstat.us/200
yahoo, https://httpstat.us/401
bcs, https://httpstat.us/521
```

The python script starts from here.

```
import time
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

url_list = []
url_data = []
total_duration = 0.5
wait_time = 5
http200_count = 0
http300_count = 0
http400_count = 0
http500_count = 0
counter = 1


with open("url_list.csv", "r") as url_file:
    headers = next(url_file).strip().replace(" ","").split(",")

    for row in url_file:
        url_list = row.strip().replace(" ","").split(",")
        url_dict = dict(zip(headers, url_list), http200 = http200_count, http300 = http300_count, http400 = http400_count, http500 = http500_count)
        url_data.append(url_dict)

url_file.close()


interval = time.time() + 60 * total_duration
print(interval)

while 1:

    while 1:
        print(f"Counter: {counter}")

        for url_entry in url_data:
            print(f"Website:", url_entry["name"])
            print(f"URL:", url_entry["url"])
            print(urllib.request.urlopen(url_entry["url"]).status)
            
            try:
                with urllib.request.urlopen(url_entry["url"]) as response:
                    print(response.status)
                    request_status = response.status
                    # return response.read(), response
            except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
                print(error.status, error.reason)
                continue
            except urllib.error.URLError as error:
                print(error.reason)
                continue
            else:
                print("All is good!")


            if request_status >= 200 and request_status <=299:
                url_entry["http200"] = url_entry["http200"] + 1
            elif request_status >= 300 and request_status <=399:
                url_entry["http300"] = url_entry["http300"] + 1
            elif request_status >= 400 and request_status <=499:
                url_entry["http400"] = url_entry["http400"] + 1
            elif request_status >= 500 and request_status <=599:
                url_entry["http500"] = url_entry["http500"] + 1
            print(f"", url_entry["name"], "-", url_entry["http200"], "-", url_entry["http300"], "-", url_entry["http400"], "-", url_entry["http500"])
            print("")
        
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        counter = counter + 1
    
        print(time.time(),"-",interval)
        if time.time() >= interval:
            print(f"There are {counter-1} probes in the past", 60 * total_duration, "secs.")
            print(f"HTTP Status code:", url_entry["name"], "-", url_entry["http200"], "-", url_entry["http300"], "-", url_entry["http400"], "-", url_entry["http500"])
            interval = time.time() + 60 * total_duration
            counter = 1
```

The problem is whenever it hits a URL with HTTP error codes it will exit and the while loop stops processing.  Is there any way to continue the script even after hitting HTTP errors?

```
➜  DevOps_Practice python urlProbe.py
1687386788.8879528
Counter: 1
Website: google
URL: https://httpstat.us/200
200
200
All is good!
 google - 1 - 0 - 0 - 0

Website: yahoo
URL: https://httpstat.us/401
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/desmondlim/Documents/DevOps/Projects/DevOps_Challenge_SPH/urlProbe.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(urllib.request.urlopen(url_entry["url"]).status)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Thanks.

Comment: This line: `print(urllib.request.urlopen(url_entry["url"]).status)` is outside the `try`. Why do you even need that, since you're opening the same URL in the `with` statement?

Comment: Do you really need to use `urllib`? The `requests` module is much easier to use.

Comment: Barmar, I am just trying to view the HTTP status returned.  And removing this line fix the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
print(urllib.request.urlopen(url_entry["url"]).status)
```

You're attempting to open the URL and print its status before entering the try-except block, and this will fail without being caught by the exceptions if the URL leads to an HTTP error. This is why your script stops.

To fix this, you should remove this line. Your try-except block already attempts to open the URL and print its status correctly.

Comment: Thanks Sash for the explanation.  Yes removing this line helps.  Thanks.